Can someone help me rectify the syntax errors and invalid effective address error?
Here is the nasm x86 assembly code to identify the missing number in the sequence of array:
[org 0x100]

jmp start

start:
mov si, 0
jmp outer

outer:
mov bx, test
mov ax, [bx+si]
mov cx, 0
jmp inner

inner:
mov dx, [array + cx]
cmp ax, dx
je increase
add cx, 2
cmp cx, 8
je found
jmp inner

increase:
add si, 2
cmp si, 10
je ends
jmp outer

found:
mov dx, ax

end:
mov ax, 0x4c00
int 0x21

array: dw 2,1,5,4
test: dw 1,2,3,4,5

The error output says that there is an error on line 10 (invalid syntax), 15 (invalid effective address), and 38 (invalid syntax):
I tried to resolve the error but it keeps giving me the same error message!
Can someone help me resolve?

mov dx, [array + cx] is not a valid a16 addressing mode, you will have to use one that is valid instead. Only bx, bp, si, or di may be used in a16 addressing modes as registers. The other two errors are likely from using the label name test which clashes with the instruction by the same name. Replace these two mentions of the label by $test or _test

[array + cx] is not a valid 16 bit addressing mode. Consult the manual or the "16 bit addressing" paragraph in this answer. je ends has a typo since your label is end. Make sure you post the code you are using along with the exact error messages. The code shown only produces these two errors here not the ones you mention.

@Jester: Interesting, which version of the assembler do you use? NASM or YASM? ETA: NASM 2.14.03 and 2.16.02 both accept the use of test as a label name.

nasm 2.12.01 and 2.16.03 both work.

@Jester: A good canonical duplicate for 16-bit addressing mode limitations is Differences between general purpose registers in 8086: [bx] works, [cx] doesn't? . I'll update my answer on the other Q&A to link that.

So Muzammil, there were three errors that I found in your code:

First up, to my knowledge, test contains a keyword, so you cannot make a variable or array out of it.
Secondly, in line 15 what does invalid address mean, that you are using registers for traversal other than iterators (BX, SI, DI). For array iteration, only these work. At least to my knowledge.
Third is actually not an error, just wanted to let you know, that I put the missing value identified in the register of CX.

So yes, here it is your updated code:
[org 0x100]

start:
    mov si, 0
    mov cx, 0

outer:
    mov bx, arr
    mov ax, [bx + si]
    add si, 2
    mov di, 0

inner:
    mov dx, [array + di]
    cmp ax, dx
    je increase
    add di, 2
    cmp di, 8
    je found
    jmp inner

increase:
    add si, 2
    cmp si, 10
    je end
    jmp outer

found: mov cx, ax

end:
    mov ax, 0x4c00
    int 0x21

arr dw 1, 2, 3, 5
array dw 1, 2, 3, 4


NASM actually does allow instruction names to be used as labels and symbol names, as long as labels are followed with : like test:, otherwise it would indeed be parsed as a test instruction with bad operands.  Some would consider it good style to avoid such name conflicts but it's not an error the way the OP's doing it.  Your version removed the : from after the label names on data, which is not a good thing.  And also gave then less meaningful names and changed the data.


you're correct, those three registers are the only ones usable for addressing into the data segment (without a ds: prefix for BP), whether you're iterating an array or not.  Differences between general purpose registers in 8086: [bx] works, [cx] doesn't?



what are you claiming isn't an error?  Are you talking about changing found: mov dx, ax to mov cx, ax for no reason?  The DOS exit system-call takes an exit status in AL, not CX or DX.  Why change the OP's code for no reason?  Also, you didn't talk about changing je ends to je end that was discussed in comments.

